# Is windows phone obsolete?

Tags: windows-mobile

When I did inquiry in some phone shops about Windows phone, they told Windows phone is obsolete, so it could not be bought. They also told it was obsolete because it was very much buggy. Only one shop told me they could provide one windows a few days latter, but it would be very buggy so they don't recommend it.

Now, my question is, really it is an obsolete product?

Comment: I am using windows phone(Lumia 520 ) for almost 3 years, and I don't think its BUGGY, !! the problem is, applications and games are limited..!! I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "buggy" and "obsolete" mean different things, so I'll answer them separately.

> Is Windows phone buggy?

Not really, unless you opt-in to the Windows Insider programme and choose the [Fast Ring](https://insider.windows.com/en-gb/how-to-overview/#definition-of-rings), which is the first to get the latest versions and new features, but is not guaranteed to be completely stable and suited for daily usage. If you're worried about stability, you can ignore that programme and stick to the standard updates.

> Is Windows phone obsolete?

I don't see why it would be. It's still being updated, as are many first- and third-party apps; it works fine as a smartphone platform as long as you know what to expect with regards to the app ecosystem; and it's still being used by probably millions of people. If you're having trouble finding phones that run Windows 10 Mobile, check online retailers like Amazon.

You might also want to check out these two great write-ups:

- [Hey Windows phone fans — ignore the haters, use what you love](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobiles-beta-test-almost-over-enter-arm-based-ultramoble-pcs)
- [Is Windows 10 Mobile still relevant in 2017 and beyond?](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/22395_Is_Windows_10_Mobile_still_rel.php)

Comment: I wish I could get a replacement Lumia 950 XL.  I miss Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows phone not obsolete, not buggy (comparing with Android, which I used before).

But it has only [1% of market](https://www.windowscentral.com/just-1-market-share-why-are-oems-choosing-windows-10-mobile).

And reason for this: not so much app for Windows phone comparing with Android and iPhone.

For example, we don't have Google Map, Google Hangout and even Pokemon Go.

And reason for this: developers don't want to develop app for Windows phone, because market is very low.

Even banks don't have mobile version for Windows phone.

So, we get some catch 22 here.

I hope Microsoft can do something to resolve this problem, because their phones are very good. And not expensive.

You can buy them directly from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/collections/Mobilelist?cat0=devices&icid=Phone_cat_AllPhonesSubNav).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone is not dead. It's a great operating system on great devices.
It just takes more people showing their phone and using it.
It sometimes feels like some users are afraid to tell that they have a windows phone, just because of the word Windows. Don't listen to these hipsters with iPhones saying it is something bad.

We are now busy creating new Windows Phone apps!

Answer (score -2):

First, WP is dead. https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/End-of-Life-Windows-Phone-ist-offiziell-tot-3769434.html I would expect another 1.5 to 2 years of updates for Windows 10 Mobile. Last phones from Microsoft are already 1.5 years old.

Windows 10 Mobile was nice and stable but following the release cycle of Windows 10, since version 1703 stability has really become an issue. I find myself sometimes restarting my Lumia 640 twice daily (main issues being: Edge browser, camera app, no internet).

On the bride side, my Lumia is 2 years old and I still don't have to worry about missing security updates. There is no other phone for 120€ I could have said the same thing about.

Comment: WOW, "-3" votes already. Seems people don't like the truths. 1) The heise.de article states that Microsoft still wants to push his services onto smartphones, just not W10M. Try finding something like OWA for iPhone. 2) Version 1607 was mature and stable while 1703 isn't. I am frequently restarting my phone. I am sure, I am not the only one... 3) Windows is getting version 1710, W10M not. MS promises only 2 years support for 1703. Who knows what comes then. Google for "lifecycle" for W10M if you don't believe me... 4) So why is W10M alive?? Because you downvote me? Good luck!

Comment: yes, you're right: [Microsoft finally admits Windows Phone is dead](https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/9/16446280/microsoft-finally-admits-windows-phone-is-dead)